# How to guarantee process once only for REST API calls for all records of a SPARK dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, hadoop, rdd

I wanted to use foreachPartition on a dataframe to send data of each row ONLY once to a REST API.

```
val aDF= ... ///sc.parallelize(0 to 1000000,4) i.e a dataframe ~1M rows
  aDF.foreachPartition(rows => {
    val hbaseConn : Connection =  ... // SET UP DB conn ==> some settings for Connection Config returns a HBaseConnection
    val httpClient : CloseableHttpClient = RESTUtil.getRestClient(...) //SET UP a http client 
    val auditHbaseTable : HBaseUtil = new HBaseUtil(hbaseConn, ...) //HBaseUtil is for DB table interactions

    val httpPost = new HttpPost("some_URL")
    httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json")

    rows.foreach( row => {
      try {
        val payload = createPayload(row)
        val entity = new StringEntity(JsonSerializationUtil.toJson(payload))
        httpPost.setEntity(entity)
        val response = httpClient.execute(httpPost)
        val responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity)
        val rowKey = UUID.randomUUID.toString
        auditHbaseTable.hbaseRecordWriter(rowKey, responseStr)
      }
      catch{
        case unknown => logger.info("Exception:" + unknown)
      }
     })
    })
```

This runs into duplicate sends most likely due to failed task retry.
I am tracking sent payloads in a hbase table for diagnostics. Its here, in audit hbase table, that I can see for some of the payloads - that multiple entries are getting made for a single payload. There are re-inserts for an already processed payload which coincides with retried tasks timestamps.

I need suggestions (with codes and references please, if possible) to ensure that spark runs only once for each row/payload.

One preventive way I could think of was to create UUID at start and keep checking in HBASE if it was sent earlier but it runs into performance issues.

```
val generateUUID=udf(()=> UUID.randomUUID().toString)
  val aDF2=aDF.withColumn("rowKey",generateUUID())
  aDF2.foreachPartition(rows => {
      ...
    rows.foreach( row => {
      try {
        if (auditHbaseTable.hbaseReader(rowKey).isEmpty){
            ...
        }
      }
        ...
    })
  })
```

So, could someone help me with a better way to do this? Is 'foreachPartiton' a correct way to go about doing this?

I am also looking at Hbase Bloom filters to speed up the above implementations but I don't know much as to how to use them. Any suggestions for that are also welcome.

Comment: If I had to implement something like that, I would have have a unique key column in the database to make sure inserts/updates are idempotent (redoing the same operations multiple times result in the same outcome).

Comment: @MichelLemay, agreed. IIRC, by design, this part wasn't supposed to be idempotent as in case of replaying earlier date for a given input data, we wanted to have separate entries tracking such a run in Hbase and not overwrite previous logged entries. Main purpose is to send data ONCE only to API.

Comment: closing thoughts on the matter..  in our case, we have a rest api that adds a unique id to each record before sending it to kinesis stream.  After that, our consumers deduplicate records based on this key.  This is usually mandatory because stream applications like kinesis or kafka are difficult to have ExactlyOnce semantic (depends on the transformations in between).  That said, I think your approach is correct when using foreachPartitions and a db connection.  Keep in mind that you can have multiple partitions executing on the same executor/node